# Java - iterate over ArrayList rows' (columns)?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, iteration

What is the simplest way to just iterate over ArrayList rows values?

For example I have two `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Object> main = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

I use two `for`s to add values into main. First I add row, then when row iterations end, I add it to main, and then repeat for another row etc. For example:

```
for(int i=0; i < somearray.length; i++){
  for(int j=0; j < somearray2.length; j++){
    if(somearray2[j] == true)
      row.add(somearray2[j]);
    }
  main.add(row);

}
```

So now I get ArrayList filled with rows like I need. But later I need to iterate over rows values, not just rows themselves from `main` `ArrayList`. How can I do that?
As I only see the method:

main.get(index), which let's me get a row, but nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes then access them as: `((ArrayList<Object>)main.get(index)).get(index2);`. But if you want all of your row element to be added to `main` array, you can make use of:

```
Collections.addAll(main, row.toArray());
```

Answer (score 7):

So, based on your description, `main` is not a list of Objects, but a list of lists. So it should be declared as

```
List<List<Object>> main = new ArrayList<>();
```

The iteration now becomes obvious:

```
for (List<Object> row : main) {
    for (Object element : row) {
        // do what you want here
    }
}
```

This has the additional advantage of making your code type-safe: you won't be able to add, inadvertently, anything other than a `List<Object>` inside the main list.